Firebase App Hosting rollout not triggered on git commit
I have tried configuring the new App Hosting service on an existing project. Everything is working except for the rollout not being triggered on a new commit on the configured git repository.
The Firebase App Hosting appears to be installed in the GitHub repository.
I suspect this is a region thing, as the project I have installed it in is in us-east1 (my understanding is that only us-central1 is supported at the moment). I do not know how to change it.
